# How to add a project reference when the DLL is in a different directory

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012

I am setting up a project that has references to DLLs that, when the application is ultimately installed, will be located in a different folder than the library I am building.  Meaning that the application directory will have all of the executable stuff, and in a subfolder will be the library (actually a great many) I am building now.

My question is about the fact that when I point to a reference in the new library's project, that seems to force the assumption that the reference will appear in the same directory as the library, meaning the subfolder I referred to before.  But in reality, it isn't.  It will be installed into the main application folder because it's part of the application itself.

So it's probably clear by now what I'm getting at.  How do I make a reference in the project that causes the library to look for the file one folder up in the hierarchy when it executes?  I have done this by editing the *.proj file by hand, but that seems messy and a source of potential mistakes.  Not to mention I have to do about 160 of these.  That's a lot of work.

Is there a purely Visual Studio interface way to point to a reference?  By the way, I cannot rely on the GAC or any such thing.  I must point to my own collection of references that are simply in a folder that I draw from.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried adding it from the `reference` and selecting on the `Project` tab..?

Comment: You should try the Project reference instead of a binary.

Comment: Are the libraries executables or DLLs?  The references will be searched from the point of view of the executing assembly.

Comment: Right click your project, click on `Add References`, select `Project` tab, browse to your other project

Comment: He's not asking how to reference it in VS, but how to make it so that the deployed executable will find the dll's in another folder.

Comment: Correct, BlackICE.  It's once the code is installed, will my subordinate DLL library be able to find what it needs, which is a different DLL in a folder one level up the hierarchy.  The library is being loaded manually in code, so I'm not sure I can even presume it to know it's "owner".

Comment: The DLL won't search for the reference, the executing assembly will.  So as long as the executable can find the dependencies of the DLL you should be fine.

Comment: @D Stanley Is that still true when the executing assembly is calling up the DLL library using Assembly.LoadFile() and then subsequently getting an instantiation using Activator.CreateInstance()?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to AssemblyResolve during initialization (Main of exe / Application_Start for web application etc) and search manually in any path you want, something like this:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
    {
        var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(basePath, e.Name + ".dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return files.Length == 1 ? Assembly.LoadFile(files[0]) : null;
    };
```